# Create for each hook function a file in WHMCS modules

Tags: php, function, whmcs

In WHMCS can i use a folder for hooks inside of hooks.php in modules/addons/ like in includes/hooks?. I test it but it don't work. and i tried to find solution by creating a folder named hooks and inside this folder i create files that contain functions: Exemple :

In modules/addons/myModule/hooks/function1.php :

```
function function1($vars){
  // .....
}
```

In modules/addons/myModule/hooks.php :

```
if (!defined("WHMCS"))
    die("This file cannot be accessed directly");
foreach (glob("hooks/*.php") as $filename)
{
    include($filename);

}
add_hook("ClientAreaHeadOutput", 1, "function1.php");
```

My solution don't work. There is any best solution for that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get an addon detected put your addon folder inside **modules/addons/**  e.g **modules/addons/mymodule** and then inside your module folder have a php file with the same name **modules/addons/mymodule/mymodule.php**. Your functions go into this file.

You will then go to **Setup** > **Addon** Modules interface and activate it.